# gluSphere on c++ mobile platform

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-platform, mosync

I have previously develop an application using openGL on windows MFC application, this is a working application. I am currently looking to port this application into mobile environment.

In the application I am using this.

```
// Wrap Texture Image to Sphere
GLUquadric *qobj = gluNewQuadric(); 
gluQuadricTexture(qobj,GL_TRUE); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTextures);
gluSphere(qobj,20.0f,32,32);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I am having trouble looking for a identical function for gluSphere() that is for non-Windows base as the .h is found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gl\GLU.h.

Any suggestion how to approach this problem? My mobile application is to be on any C++ cross-platform tools. I am currently learn MoSync while porting my application over.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606130/sphere-in-opengl-es-2-0-ios

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I am looking for the generic API got from OpenGL since I want to make my mobile application as close to as my Windows application.

Anyway, I have found out that QT for android has this gluSphere. So I am studying and learning how to develop on top of this platform.