# unable to implement rounded points using glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl

Was trying to implement rounded points logic according to this answer:

[draw circular points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098315/render-large-circular-points-in-modern-opengl)

Followed all the steps as given:

1. `glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);`
2. `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 3 );`

vertex shader:

```
#version 460

layout (location=0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location=1) in vec3 VertexColor;

layout (location=0) out vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    vColor = VertexColor;

    gl_Position = vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 2.0;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 460

layout (location=0) in vec3 vColor;
layout (location=0) out vec4 FragColor;

vec2 circCoord = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;

void main() {

    if(dot(circCoord, circCoord) > 1.0){
        discard;
    }
    FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);

}
```

but for some reason , nothing is being drawn or every fragment is being discarded. If I remove the discard statement in fragment shader I get a square point. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the circCoord calculation be part of the main method?

Comment: @BDL tried that too result is same

Comment: If I see it right you are not passing circle center to fragment (at least I do not see it, it should be a `flat` variable) and I do not also see you computing distance of fragment to center and deciding according to it ... in respect to radius which I do not see anywhere too. Instead you are using `circCoord = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;`
 which is just screen position  in <-1,+1> range ... I would expect something like  `if (length(frag_position-center_position)>radius) discard;`

Comment: @Spektre I did these two changes and now I have rounded points 1. Defined a surface format(Qt5) which was not defined 
`QSurfaceFormat canvasFormat(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
    canvasFormat.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    canvasFormat.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    canvasFormat.setVersion(4, 6);
    canvasFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(canvasFormat);` 
2. Changed the frag code to this 
`if(dot(gl_PointCoord-0.5, gl_PointCoord-0.5) > 0.25)
        discard;
    else
        FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);` 

probably the context