# What is "best practice" for drawing a sphere on Android using OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry

I've been doing some research recently on how to draw a sphere using OpenGL on Android. From what I gather, it seems there are many different answers:

- Create a square and draw a sphere over it with ray-traced impostors. [Drawing a sphere in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488086/drawing-a-sphere-in-opengl-es)
- Use blender and create a sphere there, then use that .obj file in the application
- Create a square and texture it with a circle image with appropriate shading
- Natively draw the sphere

... So my question is, what is "best practice"? I am familiarizing myself with opengl and can create squares easily enough, but is it worth the time (and gpu) to learn how to natively create the sphere?

Comment: There is no "best practice". But there's no difference between #2 and #4.

Comment: @NicolBolas by natively draw the sphere I meant creating a sphere object with opengl within the android application

Comment: I know what you meant, and my point still stands. OpenGL doesn't care where you get a mesh from. It doesn't care if you create one out of nothing or load it off of disk. All it cares about is that you have a buffer object with some vertex data in it. #2 and #4 are the same thing to the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use Blender.  Here's why.  Once you implement the code to read and parse vertex data from a POD/Collada/Obj file for OpenGL ES you will have a tool that can render any shape you can create in Blender and that is very powerful.  This is the fundamental basis of a game engine; it enables professional content creation tools.  And there are some open source SDKs out there (PowerVR) that already provide the basic pieces, plus handling textures and animations too.