# How to create one or more spheres using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, qt4

We have to create a ball game. However, before implementing our code into the graphics, we were given 3 codes for 3 types of graphics. A code for cubes, a code for random spheres which don't move, and a code for a moving cube, if i'm not mistaken (maybe i am).

First code for a cube was as follows:

```
#include "vue_opengl.h"
#include "vertex_shader.h" 
#include "contenu.h"

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessine(Contenu const& a_dessiner)
{
  Q_UNUSED(a_dessiner); 

  draw first cube (at origin)
  dessineCube();

  QMatrix4x4 matrice;
  // Dessine le 2e cube
  matrice.translate(0.0, 1.5, 0.0);
  matrice.scale(0.25);
  dessineCube(matrice);

  // Dessine le 3e cube
  matrice.setToIdentity();
  matrice.translate(0.0, 0.0, 1.5);
  matrice.scale(0.25);
  matrice.rotate(45.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  dessineCube(matrice);
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::init()
{



  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex,   ":/vertex_shader.glsl");
  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragment_shader.glsl");


  prog.bindAttributeLocation("sommet",  SommetId);
  prog.bindAttributeLocation("couleur", CouleurId);

  // Compilation of the shader openGL
  prog.link();

  // Activation of the shader
  prog.bind();


  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  initializePosition();
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::initializePosition()
{
  // position initiale
  matrice_vue.setToIdentity();
  matrice_vue.translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(60.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::translate(double x, double y, double z)
{

  QMatrix4x4 translation_supplementaire;
  translation_supplementaire.translate(x, y, z);
  matrice_vue = translation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::rotate(double angle, double dir_x, double dir_y, double dir_z)
{// Multiplie la matrice de vue par LA GAUCHE
  QMatrix4x4 rotation_supplementaire;
  rotation_supplementaire.rotate(angle, dir_x, dir_y, dir_z);
  matrice_vue = rotation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessineCube (QMatrix4x4 const& point_de_vue)
{
  prog.setUniformValue("vue_modele", matrice_vue * point_de_vue);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  // side X = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // sides X = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // green
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  // side Y = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // blue
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  //side Y = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // cyan
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // side Z = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // yellow
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);

  // side Z = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // magenta
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

  glEnd();
}
```

Now they give us the code for a sphere:

```
#include "vue_opengl.h"
#include "vertex_shader.h" 
#include "contenu.h"

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessine(Contenu const& a_dessiner)
{
  Q_UNUSED(a_dessiner); // 

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  QMatrix4x4 matrice;



  matrice.translate(-0.5, 0.0, -2.0);
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // passe en mode "fil de fer"
  dessineSphere(matrice, 0.0, 0.0); // bleu
  matrice.scale(1.5); // taille des axes (1.5 pour qu'ils dépassent un peu)

  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); // repasse en mode "plein"


}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::init()
{


  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex,   ":/vertex_shader.glsl");
  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragment_shader.glsl");


  prog.bindAttributeLocation("sommet",  SommetId);
  prog.bindAttributeLocation("couleur", CouleurId);


  prog.link();

  // Activation du shader
  prog.bind();

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  sphere.initialize();                                      // initialise la sphère
  initializePosition();
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::initializePosition()
{
  // position initial
  matrice_vue.setToIdentity();
  matrice_vue.translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(60.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::translate(double x, double y, double z)
{

  QMatrix4x4 translation_supplementaire;
  translation_supplementaire.translate(x, y, z);
  matrice_vue = translation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::rotate(double angle, double dir_x, double dir_y, double dir_z)
{
  // 
  QMatrix4x4 rotation_supplementaire;
  rotation_supplementaire.rotate(angle, dir_x, dir_y, dir_z);
  matrice_vue = rotation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessineCube (QMatrix4x4 const& point_de_vue)
{
  prog.setUniformValue("vue_modele", matrice_vue * point_de_vue);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  // side X = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // rouge
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // side X = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // vert
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  // face coté Y = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // bleu
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  // side Y = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // cyan
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // side Z = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // jaune
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);

  //side Z = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // magenta
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

  glEnd();
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessineSphere (QMatrix4x4 const& point_de_vue,
                               double rouge, double vert, double bleu)
{
  prog.setUniformValue("vue_modele", matrice_vue * point_de_vue);
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, rouge, vert, bleu);  // met la couleur
  sphere.draw(prog, SommetId);                           // dessine la sphère
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessineAxes (QMatrix4x4 const& point_de_vue, bool en_couleur)
{
  prog.setUniformValue("vue_modele", matrice_vue * point_de_vue);

  glBegin(GL_LINES);

  // axe X
  if (en_couleur) {
    prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // rouge
  } else {
    prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // blanc
  }    
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  // axe Y
  if (en_couleur) prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // green
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

  // axe Z
  if (en_couleur) prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // blue
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  glEnd();
}
```

LAST CODE: moving cube: - i assume we have to put the sphere in this code so that it moves:

```
#include "vue_opengl.h"
#include "vertex_shader.h" // Identifiants Qt de nos différents attributs
#include "contenu.h"

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessine(Contenu const& a_dessiner)
{
   // Dessine le 1er cube (à l'origine)
  dessineCube();

  QMatrix4x4 matrice;


  // Dessine le 4e cube
  matrice.setToIdentity();
  matrice.rotate(a_dessiner.infos(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  matrice.translate(0.0, 2.3, 0.0);
  matrice.scale(0.2);
  dessineCube(matrice);
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::init()
{


  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex,   ":/vertex_shader.glsl");
  prog.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragment_shader.glsl");



  prog.bindAttributeLocation("sommet",  SommetId);
  prog.bindAttributeLocation("couleur", CouleurId);

  // Compilation du shader OpenGL
  prog.link();

  // Activation du shader
  prog.bind();


  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  initializePosition();
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::initializePosition()
{
  // position initiale
  matrice_vue.setToIdentity();
  matrice_vue.translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(60.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  matrice_vue.rotate(45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::translate(double x, double y, double z)
{

  QMatrix4x4 translation_supplementaire;
  translation_supplementaire.translate(x, y, z);
  matrice_vue = translation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::rotate(double angle, double dir_x, double dir_y, double dir_z)
{

  QMatrix4x4 rotation_supplementaire;
  rotation_supplementaire.rotate(angle, dir_x, dir_y, dir_z);
  matrice_vue = rotation_supplementaire * matrice_vue;
}

// ======================================================================
void VueOpenGL::dessineCube (QMatrix4x4 const& point_de_vue)
{
  prog.setUniformValue("vue_modele", matrice_vue * point_de_vue);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  // face coté X = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // rouge
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // face coté X = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // vert
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  // face coté Y = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // bleu
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);

  // face coté Y = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // cyan
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);

  // face coté Z = +1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // jaune
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, +1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, +1.0);

  // face coté Z = -1
  prog.setAttributeValue(CouleurId, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // magenta
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, -1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, +1.0, -1.0);
  prog.setAttributeValue(SommetId, +1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

  glEnd();
}
```

How do i implement all 3 of these codes to display a sphere that is moving and is one solid colour?

Comment: apologies part of the code is in french but dessine means to draw

Comment: My answer here explains a few options for drawing spheres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137198/opengl-es-2-0-sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use GLU library? GLU has a primitive type for Sphere. Here is [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluSphere.xml)

**Example of usage:**

Quadratic initialization:

```
quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH);
```

Draw function:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef("TranslateX here","TranslateY here","TranslateZ here");
gluSphere(quadratic,"Sphere Radius here", 32, 32);
glPopMatrix();
```