# How drawing sphere in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

How can I draw a sphere in Android using OpenGL ES?

Comment: you should check API Demo example

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which version of OpenGL ES (1.x, 2.0)? Do you know how to use OpenGL ES at all? As @HardikNadiyapara said, you should really look at the Android tutorials first, e.g. http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html. Btw, you should not ask "please do this for me and send me the code"-questions on SO (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is possible duplicate of the below questions:

[Problem drawing a sphere in OPENGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072308/problem-drawing-a-sphere-in-opengl-es)

[Drawing a sphere in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488086/drawing-a-sphere-in-opengl-es)

I will advise you to do some research before asking the question, as there are many tutorial available for the same :

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

If you face any issue or problem while trying then should ask the question with the real problem.

Thanks.