# Android OpenGL 2.0 Creating a Sphere

Tags: android, geometry, opengl-es-2.0

Now this may seem like a silly question but I cant for the life of me find a tutorial/example on how to create a Sphere in OpenGL 2.0 for Android.

I can find OpenGL 1.x version but I am using GLES20.

Can anyone show me the way?

Comment: Use search before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842767/how-drawing-sphere-in-android

Comment: I did, first one is OpenGL 1.x, second 1 is for iOS, third link is what I been following but sadly does not cover sphere!

Comment: why don't you make your own?

Comment: What as an imported object? like a obj? or actually work out the vertices